# How to add reference of c# system.drawing to unity3d project?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

in my unity3d project code i have this method : i want to use Bitmap GraphicsPath BitmapData Rectangle and more but they are all missing reference.

I tried to google for it some result suggest to change in the unity editor Project Settings > Player API Compatibility level to .NET 2.1 but it didn't much help.  it did add some System.Drawing but not the csharp one.

a bit messed.

```
private void FindPoints()
    {
        Bitmap bmptest;
        GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
        int x, y, p, j, wdthHght;
        int bytes;
        byte[] rgbValuesWithClouds;
        byte[] rgbValuesWithoutClouds;
        IntPtr ptr;
        Rectangle rect;
        BitmapData bitmap_Data;

        Bitmap bmpWithClouds; //No memory is allocated
        Bitmap bmpWithoutClouds; //No memory is allocated

        gp.AddEllipse(new RectangleF(73, 72, 367, 367));

        //using the using statement, bmpWithClouds bitmap is automatically disposed at the end of statement. No memory leaks :)
        using (bmpWithClouds = new Bitmap(mymem))
        {
            rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmpWithClouds.Width, bmpWithClouds.Height);
            wdthHght = bmpWithClouds.Width;

            //Lock bitmap to copy its color information fast
            bitmap_Data = bmpWithClouds.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmpWithClouds.PixelFormat);
            ptr = bitmap_Data.Scan0;
            bytes = bitmap_Data.Stride * bmpWithClouds.Height;

            rgbValuesWithClouds = new byte[bytes];

            //copy color information to rgbValues array
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValuesWithClouds, 0, bytes);
            //we are done copying so unlock bitmap. We dont need it anymore
            bmpWithClouds.UnlockBits(bitmap_Data);
        }

        //using the using statement, bmpWithClouds bitmap is automatically disposed at the end of statement. No memory leaks :)
        using (bmpWithoutClouds = new Bitmap(@"F:\Drive Backup\Samsung Galaxy S9\Danny Backup\Recovered data 02-10 18_32_36\1  (D) NTFS\C-Sharp\Weather Radar\WithoutClouds.bmp")) //24 bit bitmap
        {
            rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmpWithoutClouds.Width, bmpWithoutClouds.Height);

            //Lock bitmap to copy its color information fast
            bitmap_Data = bmpWithoutClouds.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmpWithoutClouds.PixelFormat);
            ptr = bitmap_Data.Scan0;
            bytes = bitmap_Data.Stride * bmpWithoutClouds.Height;

            rgbValuesWithoutClouds = new byte[bytes];

            //copy color information to rgbValues array
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValuesWithoutClouds, 0, bytes);
            //we are done copying so unlock bitmap. We dont need it anymore
            bmpWithoutClouds.UnlockBits(bitmap_Data);
        }

        // Each position in these arrays, rgbValuesWithoutClouds and rgbValuesWithClouds, corresponds a color. eg
        // First pixel   Second pixel   Third pixel   Forth pixel .... // bitmaps
        //    B G R          B G R         B G R         B G R    .... // rgbValues arrays
        bmptest = new Bitmap(512, 512);
        cloudPoints = new List<Point>();

        for (y = 0; y < wdthHght; y++)
        {
            j = 0;
            for (x = 0; x < wdthHght; x++)
            {
                p = y * wdthHght * 3 + j;

                if (rgbValuesWithClouds[p] != rgbValuesWithoutClouds[p])
                {
                    cloudPoints.Add(new Point(x, y));
                    bmptest.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Red);
                }

                j += 3;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: just in general: You did read the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.drawing#remarks)?

Comment: Why do you need System.Drawing? Unity has almost all of those features already I’m pretty sure.